# How to fix an unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float' error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to calculate the limiting reagent but I am recieving this error once it get to that part of the calculations at the line:

```
gramOxygenAA = (moleOxygen * (2/1)) * ((12.011*2) + (1.008*4) + (15.9994 * 2))
```

This is my code:

```
# Function that determines moles of oxygen input
def moleOxygen (gramOxygen):
    moleOxygen = gramOxygen / (15.9994 * 2)
    print ("Moles of oxygen available:", format(moleOxygen,'.2f'))
    return (moleOxygen)


# Function that determines moles of acetaldehyde input
def moleAcetaldehyde (gramAcetaldehyde):
    moleAcetaldehyde = gramAcetaldehyde / ((12.011*2) + (1.008*4) + 15.999)
    print ("Moles of acetaldehyde available:", format(moleAcetaldehyde,'.2f'))
    return moleAcetaldehyde


# Function that determines grams of Acetic Acid produced from available oxygen
def gramOxygenAA (moleOxygen): 
    gramOxygenAA = (moleOxygen * (2/1)) * ((12.011*2) + (1.008*4) + (15.9994 * 2))
    print ("Grams of Acetic Acid that can be produced from available oxygen is", format(gramOxygenAA,'.2f'))
    return gramOxygenAA


# Function that determines grams of Acetic Acid produced from available acetaldehyde
def gramAcetaldehydeAA ():
    gramAcetaldehydeAA = (moleAcetaldehyde / (2/2)) *((12.011*2) + (1.008*4) + (15.9994 * 2))
    print ("Grams of Acetic Acid that can be produced from available acetaldehyde is", format(gramAcetaldehydeAA, '.2f'))
    return gramAcetaldehydeAA


# Function that determines the Limiting Reagent
def limitingReagent():
    if gramOxygenAA < gramAcetaldehydeAA:
        smaller = gramOxygenAA
        print ("Oxygen is the limiting reagent")

    else:
        smaller = gramAcetaldehydeAA
        print ("Acetaldehyde is the limiting reagent")

    return smaller


def main ():
    gramOxygen = float (input("Enter grams of oxygen entered into the reaction: "))
    gramAcetaldehyde = float (input("Enter grams of acetaldehyde entered into the reaction: "))

    print ("*" * 80)

    moleOxygen (gramOxygen)
    moleAcetaldehyde (gramAcetaldehyde)
    gramOxygenAA (moleOxygen)
    gramAcetaldehydeAA ()

    limitingReagent()
    print ("The number of grams of acetic acid produced due to limiting reagent is", format (smaller,'.2f'))


### Call to main program ###
main ()
```

My edited changed code:

```
# Function that determines moles of oxygen input
def moleOxygen (gramOxygen):
    molesOxygen = gramOxygen / (15.9994 * 2)
    print ("Moles of oxygen available:", format(molesOxygen,'.2f'))
    return (molesOxygen)


# Function that determines moles of acetaldehyde input
def moleAcetaldehyde (gramAcetaldehyde):
    molesAcetaldehyde = gramAcetaldehyde / ((12.011*2) + (1.008*4) + 15.999)
    print ("Moles of acetaldehyde available:", format(molesAcetaldehyde,'.2f'))
    return molesAcetaldehyde


# Function that determines grams of Acetic Acid produced from available oxygen
def gramOxygenAA (): 
    gramsOxygen = (moleOxygen * (2/1)) * ((12.011*2) + (1.008*4) + (15.9994 * 2))
    print ("Grams of Acetic Acid that can be produced from available oxygen is", format(gramsOxygenAA,'.2f'))
    return gramsOxygen


# Function that determines grams of Acetic Acid produced from available acetaldehyde
def gramAcetaldehydeAA ():
    gramsAcetaldehydeAA = (molesAcetaldehyde / (2/2)) *((12.011*2) + (1.008*4) + (15.9994 * 2))
    print ("Grams of Acetic Acid that can be produced from available acetaldehyde is", format(gramsAcetaldehydeAA, '.2f'))
    return gramsAcetaldehydeAA


# Function that determines the Limiting Reagent
def limitingReagent():
    if gramsOxygen < gramsAcetaldehydeAA:
        smaller = gramsOxygen
        print ("Oxygen is the limiting reagent")

    else:
        smaller = gramsAcetaldehydeAA
        print ("Acetaldehyde is the limiting reagent")

    return smaller


def main ():
    gramOxygen = float (input("Enter grams of oxygen entered into the reaction: "))
    gramAcetaldehyde = float (input("Enter grams of acetaldehyde entered into the reaction: "))

    print ("*" * 80)

    moleOxygen (gramOxygen)
    moleAcetaldehyde (gramAcetaldehyde)
    gramOxygenAA ()
    gramAcetaldehydeAA ()

    limitingReagent()
    print ("The number of grams of acetic acid produced due to limiting reagent is", format (smaller,'.2f'))


### Call to main program ###
main ()
```

But I still get the same error... so sad...

Comment: your function name and variable name are the same...You need to change that

Comment: You define `def gramOxygenAA (moleOxygen):` so, `gramOxygenAA` is a function. You then use that same name to assign an numeric value to it. Choose another name for the variable.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I took you tip and changed the variable name but I still ended up with the same error! (T.T)

Comment: This happens many times in your program. Did you change all instances? See also in `main`.  There you first call `moleOxgen(gramOxygen)` but again use `moleOxygen` as a variable. You should assign the return value of `moleOxgen(gramOxygen)` to a variable and pass that variable to the next function.

Comment: yep, I had changed all my variables that way it would be different from the function definition (indicated above), but I still get the same error.... I can't seem to figure out why,